# Default field values?

Tags: field, fieldtypes

This seems so simple, but after reading over the docs, I couldn't find an answer:

Is there a way to have a field have a default value in Craft?

In my case, I have a Lightswitch field that I want to be on by default, so my client doesn't have to turn it on every time they publish an asset.  But they still do need the ability to turn it off in exceptional cases.

I realize I could just reverse the logic of the field, but it raises a broader question of default field values (which would be useful to me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, the only fields that allow defaults are those that extend the [BaseOptionsFieldType](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/fieldtypes/BaseOptionsFieldType), namely Dropdown, Multiselect, Checkboxes, and RadioButtons. You could change your lightswitch to one of these other fieldtypes and have a default value available.

Answer (score 2):

I just submitted a feature request to have an `entries.onBeforeEditEntry` event. This should make it possible to have default values for all sort of field types from a plugin.

[Raise an event before entry is edited/loaded in CP](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7494886-raise-an-event-before-entry-is-edited-loaded-in-cp)

Comment: Apparently Brandon added a hook in response to your request. Does this now make it possible to set defaults? If so, could you perhaps expand your answer with a code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **[feature request to add a default value](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10862/how-to-use-a-numeric-field-with-a-default-value)** to the native Number field type – voting for it will hopefully bring this functionality to Craft CMS.

(Also, Brad Bell [suggests another solution](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/10863/37): Write a plugin that extends Craft's native Number field type.)