# How to use a Numeric Field with a Default Value

Tags: field, integer

I have a case where I need to use a numeric field which also has a default value.

For example: `numericField` needs to have a minimum value of 100 and a max value of 1000, but when the user adds a new entry, the field value should default to 256 in the entry form.

Unfortunately, I cannot trust the user to enter the correct default value, even if it is clearly indicated in the field notes.

Right now, when the user adds a new entry, `numericField` will always be set to 100 the minimum value.

Is there another integer field type which would work as I have described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1) Write a plugin that extends Craft's native Number field type and adds the functionality you're looking for.

2) Make a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com) for a default value for the native Number field type.

3) Potentially fake it using something like the [CP CSS](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) plugin.

Comment: Thanks, Brad.  I added a feature request for this. Using a plugin for this seems like overkill.